# How to read an Excel CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, excel

```py
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd']

pattern_counts = {}

for i in range(len(data)-2):
    pattern = str(data[i]) + str(data[i+1]) + str(data[i+2])
    if pattern in pattern_counts:
        pattern_counts[pattern] += 1
    else:
        pattern_counts[pattern] = 1

for pattern, count in pattern_counts.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(pattern, count))
```

When this code runs, it prints a list of patterns for 3 value sets. It does this efficiently and accurately.

Here's my question: How do I make it read an Excel CSV file with vertical values descending downwards?

So far I have tried and will continue to try dissecting the code in order to realize how to convert it to read cells.

Comment: Please clarify what is an "excel csv". Is it an Excel file as in a .xlsx/.xls file? Or is it a regular CSV-formatted text file that you just open in Excel? Can you open it as a regular text file? If it is really plain CSV, please [edit] to show sample contents.

Comment: Python has a built-in csv module for reading CSV files: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html